# How to combine 2 vuex stores into a single store

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

Hi i have a requirement of combining 2 `vuex` store into a single store (**both stores are of different projects**)

```
import storeA from '/path';

import storeB from '/path';
```

**now combined both store**

```
const combinedStore = //combine logic as i don't know this logic
```

I searched a lot on stackoverflow to combine 2 vuex store but i did not find any solution so posted.

here is how my `vuex` store will look like in both the `stores`

**Store 1:**

```
   // storeA.js
    
    const store = {
        state(){return {}},
        actions: {async getData(){...}},
        mutations: {},
        getters: {}, 
        modules:{ 
           Login
        }
    }
```

**Store 2:**

```
   // storeB.js
    
    const store = {
        state(){return {}},
        actions: {async getUsers(){...}},
        mutations: {},
        getters: {}, 
        modules:{ 
           workflow
        }
    }
```

**Here is how i tried:**

```
import StoreA from 'storeA.js';
import StoreB from 'storeB.js';

const newStoreData = Object.assign({},StoreA,StoreB)

const newStore = new Vuex.Store({
    ...newStoreData
});
```

Now only 1 store will work other will throw error like

> reading first_name name of undefined (i,e `state.[module].first_name`)

**Problem can be re-produced here:** https://codesandbox.io/s/vuex-playground-forked-1h344?file=/src/main.js

**Original working fork:** https://codesandbox.io/s/k012qvkmnv?file=/src/main.js

Comment: You can't combine two stores which is of wrong context but you can combine two modules wherein each module can have its own states, getters, mutations and actions.

Comment: created 2 separate store in this example which is re-producing my problem https://codesandbox.io/s/vuex-playground-forked-1h344?file=/src/App.vue     Original working code here https://codesandbox.io/s/k012qvkmnv

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Vue 3+**

Lower versions probably have this method too but I’m not sure.

```js
import StoreA from 'storeA.js';
import StoreB from 'storeB.js';

const newStore = new Vuex.Store(storeA);

newStore.registerModule('', storeB)
```

I just modified `store2.js` and `main.js` files

link to solved problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/vuex-playground-forked-6pg4w?file=/src/main.js

Here is a documentation about it: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#dynamic-module-registration

Comment: getting **Error**  `Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function` despite following your steps

Comment: @EaB Are you using vuex 4+ ?

Comment: ...@Mises i'm using `"vuex": "^3.6.0"`

Comment: @EaB Edited for version 3.x

Comment: ...@Mises this approach of combining 2 modules i already know.  this solution is not flexible if i already have dedicated modules for each plugins. in core side again we need to define module. then change whole code in plugin (to access like this `store.state.a`). not flexible solution if we keep in mind that my plugin can be used with anywhere.

Comment: created 2 separate store in this example which is re-producing my problem https://codesandbox.io/s/vuex-playground-forked-1h344?file=/src/App.vue     Original working code here https://codesandbox.io/s/k012qvkmnv

Comment: @EaB Edited post this way you can extend your main store with modules and actions will work.